# Interaction Hamiltonian for the classical current's radiation in the coherent state

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

As I understand, for the classical current's radiation in the coherent state, its generation is explained by the following interaction Hamiltonian:

$H_{int}(t)=\int \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r},t)\cdot \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{r},t)d\mathbf{r}$

where $\mathbf{J}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ are the classical current and quantum vector potential respectively.

Would you explain how the $H_{int}$ is derived?

I am not sure whether one can extract the $H_{int}$ from the Hamiltonian for a charged particle in the field:
$\mathcal{H}=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}+qV$,
where $p$ and $V$ are the mechanical momentum of the particle and scalar potential respectively.